# A power series with poles on its convergence circumference

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove this: If a power series has poles of its sum function on its convergent circumference, then the power series diverges everywhere on its convergent circumference.

For example: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n$ has a pole at $z=1$, so for all $|w|=1$,we have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty w^n$ diverges.

I've learned about analytic continuation, but I don't know how to use it for poles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that Abel's theorem says that if $\sum b_n =b$ then $\lim_{r \to 1^-}\sum b_nr^n=b$

But now let $f$ as in the OP a power series with at least a pole on its (finite) radius of convergence; by translation, scaling, and rotation we can assume wlog that $f(z)=\sum a_nz^n$ converges precisely on the unit disc and $f$ has a pole at $1$ (meaning, there is a meromorphic extension of $f$ in a small neighborhood of $1$ with a pole at $1$ and analytic everywhere else there)

But then if there is a $|w|=1$ for which $\sum a_nw^n$ converges, it follows that $a_n \to 0$ hence $b_n=a_n-a_{n-1}, n \ge 1, b_0=a_0$ satisfies $\sum b_n=0$. so by Abel theorem $\sum b_nr^n \to 0, r\to 1^-$

But we notice that $\sum b_nz^n=(1-z)\sum a_nz^n=(1-z)f(z)$ so one on hand $(1-r)f(r) \to 0, r \to 1^-$ but on the other hand because of the pole at $1$ we have either $(1-r)f(r) \to c \ne 0$ if the pole is of order $1$ or $|(1-r)f(r)| \to \infty$ if the pole is of order at least $2$ and that is a contradiction either way!